# Assign a integer number to toolbar as title in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am developing Android project in Kotlin.

I got my toolbar:

```
@BindView(R.id.tool_bar)
lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
```

I want to set its title :

```
// student.id is a int type
toolbar.title =  student.id
```

Student's id is a `Int` type. toolbar.title expects a value of type `CharSequence`. How to assign my id to toolbar's title? I mean how can I convert `student.id` to `CharSequence` so that I can assign it to my toolbar title ?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
toolbar.title = student.id.toString()
```

Comment: No, compiler still complains

Comment: @Leem: Complains about *what*? [`String` is an implementation of `CharSequence`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String), and [`toString()` on `Int` returns a `String`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/to-string.html).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try kotlin string template for your case

```
toolbar.title = "${student.id}"
```

Comment: @Leem did you try my solution

Answer (score 0):

This is best way to convert any type of number numbers (int, float, double) into string:-

```
toolbar.title = "" + student.id
```

Remember one thing, `""` this must be before the number.

After that, put a `+` and then, put any type of number.

This technique is supported by many programming languages like Java, Kotlin, Javascipt etc.